# Problem Converting Caffe model to dlc using SNPE

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, qualcomm, snpe

I am facing an issue in converting my caffe model to dlc using SNPE.

Specifically in the "Scale" layer.

The first two layers are as follows

```
name: "First"
  input: "data"
  input_shape {
  dim: 1
  dim: 3
  dim: xxx
  dim: xxx
} 

layer {
  name: "data/Scale"
  type: "Scale"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "data/Scale"
  scale_param {
    filler: {
      value: 0.0078125   
    }
    bias_term: true
    bias_filler: {
      value: -1
    }
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
    decay_mult: 0
  }
}

layer {
  name: "Conv2d_0/convolution"
  type: "Convolution"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 32
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 2
  }
  bottom: 'data/Scale'
  top: "Conv2d_0/convolution"
}
```

I get the following error:

```
('Encountered Error:', 'list index out of range')

Stack Trace:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/nithin.ga/SNPE_19/snpe-1.19.2/bin/x86_64-linux-clang/snpe-caffe-to-dlc", line 115, in <module>
    args.enable_strict_validation)

  File "/home/nithin.ga/SNPE_19/snpe-1.19.2/lib/python/snpe/snpe_caffe_to_dlc.py", line 1145, in convert
    self.convert_caffe_new(self.spec)

  File "/home/nithin.ga/SNPE_19/snpe-1.19.2/lib/python/snpe/snpe_caffe_to_dlc.py", line 1327, in convert_caffe_new
    layer_seq = self._blob_connectivity_map.check_s_folding(layer)

  File "/home/nithin.ga/SNPE_19/snpe-1.19.2/lib/python/snpe/snpe_caffe_to_dlc.py", line 459, in check_s_folding

output_layer = self._blobs[prev_layer_output_blob]['output_of_layers'][0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: were you able to run your network with caffe? x86/support arch.

Comment: @kzs I found out the issue....The Scale layer for SNPE must always be preceded by batchnorm layer else scale layer will not work

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation for the Scale layer limitation of SNPE:

https://developer.qualcomm.com/docs/snpe/limitations.html

> **Batch normalization (+ Scaling)**
>
> - Caffe: Scaling (scale_layer) is optional. If present, it extends functionality of Batch normalization (batch_norm_layer). If not present, batch_norm_layer will still be converted as per Caffe specification. scale_layer used anywhere else in the network but immediately after the batch_norm_layer is not supported.

There is support for scaling, but only if it's part of the data layer:

https://developer.qualcomm.com/docs/snpe/network_layers.html

> Scale (Image)
>
> Input image scaling, maintains aspect ratio. This function is
>   primarily intended for images, but technically any 2D input data can
>   be processed if it makes sense. Scaling parameters are provided as an
>   option to the model converter tool.
>
> There is no such Caffe layer by itself. This functionality is
>   technically part of the Caffe data provider.